# D3DXGetImageInfoFromFile function

Tags: c++, direct3d, d3dx

Using `D3DXGetImageInfoFromFile()` function gives me this:

`Unhandled exception at 0x004114d4 in SAMPLE.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000000.`

Here is the piece of code that contains error:

```
// ...
WCHAR           *Path = L"./LIFE.bmp";
D3DXIMAGE_INFO      *Info;
IDirect3DSurface9   *Surface = NULL;
LPDIRECT3DDEVICE9   pd3dDevice;

// ...
D3DXGetImageInfoFromFile(Path, Info); // everything is fine here, unless i do the following:
pd3dDevice -> CreateOffscreenPlainSurface(Info->Width, Info->Height, Info->Format, D3DPOOL_SYSTEMMEM, &Surface, NULL);
```

So, what is happening here? And when I type in numbers instead of `Info->...`, everything works fine...

Comment: i wish i knew) i just throws an exception. without the D3DXGetImageInfoFromFile() function it works smoothly. i even re-installed the SDK. nothing works.

Comment: thats why i provided the whole listing

Comment: what is the exception? Be precise.

Comment: it says : "an unhandled win32 exception occured in DIRECTX_001.exe [1296]"

Comment: Do you get anything more informative when you run under the debugger?

Comment: do you think it could be corrupted libs?

Comment: Never heard of corrupted libs occuring

Comment: ok. can LPCWSTR type cause trouble? (`wsPath` variable)

Comment: No probs with wide chars. Try on some other machines. Could be a messed up driver.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You pass **uninitialized** pointer `Info` and when method tries to access you get the exception. What you need is the following:

```
D3DXIMAGE_INFO Info;
D3DXGetImageInfoFromFile(Path, &Info);
pd3dDevice->CreateOffscreenPlainSurface(Info.Width, Info.Height, Info.Format, D3DPOOL_SYSTEMMEM, &Surface, NULL);
```

Also, I'd recommend you handling result codes of any function that returns HRESULT. Like:

```
if (FAILED(D3DXGetImageInfoFromFile(Path, &Info))) {
  // print something, abort or whatever.
}
```

If you use **DXUT.h** then `V()` or `V_RESULT` macros are your best friends:

```
V(D3DXGetImageInfoFromFile(Path, &Info));
```

OR

```
HRESULT hr;
V_RETURN(D3DXGetImageInfoFromFile(Path, &Info));
V_RETURN(pd3dDevice->CreateOffscreenPlainSurface(Info.Width, Info.Height, Info.Format, D3DPOOL_SYSTEMMEM, &Surface, NULL));
V_RETURN(...);
// ... lots of D3D calls.
return S_OK;
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to escape the backslash in the path to your image:

```
std::wstring wsPath = L"C:\\wood.bmp";
```

Comment: you was right after all!! )) turns out it was just part of the problem.

Comment: @Abdulali, what was the other part?